# Keyword not supported: 'filedsn'

Tags: c#

I have a File DSN name "Edat.dsn". I want to use it to fetch some data

```
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = @"FILEDSN=C:\edat.dsn;";
            string query = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS Expr1 FROM  dbo.datle";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    i = oReader["Expr1"].ToString();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

but it says

> Keyword not supported: 'filedsn'.

how can I use a File DSN to fetch some data in sql database?

Comment: That is for ODBC. You are connecting to a SQL Server instance.

Comment: [Look it up](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSN is used for ODBC connections and you are using the SQL connection. So either switch to ODBCConnection or make the change in your connection string to use the SQL Server. You can refer the [connectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

So your connection string would be like

```
<connectionstrings> 
   <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="DSN=ram"   providerName="System.Data.odbc" />
</connectionstring>
```